# Unprotect the Excel workbooks in a specified path and refresh the workbook conection and then protec the workbooks

Tags: excel, vba

I want to unprotect the excel workbooks in a specified path using the same password. I've used the below code to do the process.

```
Sub Unlock_Refresh()

Dim path As String, w As Worksheet, pass As String, wb As Workbooks
pass = "1519"
Worksheets("Sheet2").Select
path = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").Value

For Each wb In path

wb.Unprotect Password:=pass

Next wb

ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll

Application.Wait ("00:00:10")

For Each wb In path

wb.Protect Password:=pass

Next wb

End Sub
```

It won't work. Can someone help me on this.

Comment: Please explain what is `It won't work`, is there an error? If so - which line did it occured and what's the error code/msg? If it's not working as expected then in what way?

Comment: `path` is string so you have nothing (and can't) loop using `For Each`. Is `path` a path of a folder or a specific path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Application.Wait ("00:00:10")` pauses the macro till 10 seconds past midnight which is not what you wanted I guess. Use `Dir` to iterate over the files in the directory, open the workbook, refresh , close and save.

```vb
Sub Unlock_Refresh()

    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
    Dim Filepath As String, Filename As String
    Dim n As Long
    Dim books As New Collection
    
    Const pass = "1519"
    Filepath = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").Value
    If Right(Filepath, 1) <> "\" Then Filepath = Filepath & "\"
    
    Filename = Dir(Filepath & "*.xls*")
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Do While Filename <> ""
        n = n + 1
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filepath & Filename, Password:=pass)
        books.Add wb, CStr(n)
        Filename = Dir
    Loop
    ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll
    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:10")
    
    ' close books
    For Each wb In books
        wb.Close SaveChanges:=False
    Next
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    MsgBox n & " workbooks opened and refreshed " & vbLf & Filepath, vbInformation
    
End Sub
```

Comment: I've tried this code. But, it is asking for the password to open the excel file. the code won't execute "with wb" portion.

Comment: @Dhakshna Add the password into the open statement `Workbooks.Open(Filepath & Filename, Password:=pass)`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69866477/unprotect-the-excel-workbooks-in-a-specified-path-and-refresh-the-workbook-conec

Please can you help me with this.

Comment: @Dhakshna is there a problem with this script or is it with your PowerQuery after the script has run ?

Comment: There is no problem in this script. It will refresh the Workbooks which i was specified in Filepath. But actually it should refresh my mastersheet instead of the File path workbooks.

To calrify, the code will unprotect the workbooks in the file path and it should refresh my mastersheet then the workbooks get protected again.(I've pasted the above code in my mastersheet).

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: @dhakshna OK see update