# Unprotect the Excel workbooks in a specified path and refresh the workbook conection and then protect the workbooks

Tags: excel, vba

To elaborate([Unprotect the Excel workbooks in a specified path and refresh the workbook conection and then protec the workbooks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69865023/unprotect-the-excel-workbooks-in-a-specified-path-and-refresh-the-workbook-conec/69865843#69865843))

I've a four workbooks in a specific path used by different users. I've used the power query to consolidate the workbooks with my Mastersheet using Data--> Refreshall. Some of the internal team issues I'm in a situation of protecting the workbooks.

After the initiation, the mastersheet won't get refreshed it indicates '[DataFormat.Error] File contains corrupted data.'. When i'm unprotecting the workbook, it worked properly.

So, please help me with this.

```
Option Explicit
Sub Unlock_Refresh()

    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
    Dim Filepath As String, Filename As String
    Dim n As Long
    
    Const pass = "1519"
    Filepath = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").Value
    If Right(Filepath, 1) <> "\" Then Filepath = Filepath & "\"
    
    Filename = Dir(Filepath & "*.xls*")
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Do While Filename <> ""
        
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filepath & Filename, Password:=pass)
        With wb
            .Unprotect Password:=pass
            .RefreshAll
            Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:10")
            .Protect Password:=pass
            .Close savechanges:=True
        End With
        n = n + 1
        Filename = Dir

    Loop
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    MsgBox n & " workbooks refreshed in " & vbLf & Filepath, vbInformation    
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried to perform your operations manually without using this macro ?  Did you get corrupt data error as well?

Comment: Bit confused by your language. Can you state which line of code results the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know if this is related to the issue you're having or not, but there appears to be some logical disconnections in your code.
Line:

```
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filepath & Filename, Password:=pass)
```

Opens a workbook using a password that would be required only if the book was password protected to open. I note here:
a)  this line of code will work even of no 'password-to-open' was set
b)  as the code doesn't set a password-to-open, one assumes that is done manually?

Lines:

```
.Unprotect Password:=pass
.RefreshAll
.Protect Password:=pass
```

Un-protects the book-structure (and windows), refreshes external data, then re-protects the book-structure (only).  I note here:
a)  book-structure protection doesn't need to be off, in order to refresh external data
b)  this doesn't set the 'password-to-open'
So it's unclear why the un-protect and re-protect logic cycle is there?

In case it's relevant, the following code would be used to set the 'password-to-open':

```
[workbook].Protect = pass
```